# Decreasing the range of wifi signals

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I want to know if we can somehow make the wifi signals propogate in a single direction. Is it possible? Or Can we decrease the range of the wi-fi chips or adapters in linux? I have tried setting the tx power to low in my dell laptop but it doesn't seem to work.
I am using kali linux as the os and used the internal adapter. It's the same case with Raspberry pi also.

Comment: Is it possible to add the reasons for lowering the signal so that you can get more options?

Comment: I want to get the list of devices within a specified range or say in a room of 100sqft area. I am using kismet and am able to detect the devices. So I want to limit the range to the area of the room.

Comment: The only way to limit the range at with you detect devices (this is RX - reception) is to modify the antenna or the room conditions. There is no control on RX afaik for any device.

Comment: I seem to think that a lot of folks doing wifi surveys tend to favour USB wireless adaptors with screw on antennae for stuff like this. You can then install a directional antenna to that, though the specifics and legality may vary

Comment: What OS was it on the Dell when you tried it and it didn't work? Are you using the internal adapter/card or was it USB? Update the question with as much info as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Antenna will have the greatest impact.  One shaped like a dish will limit reception to 180 degrees, but extend the range.

Unscrew the antenna completely, and it may not work at all or the range may only be inches.

Obviously consult your local laws, but the smaller the antenna the less range.

Specific sizes and shapes will increase/narrow the fields of view.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to block the propagation of WiFi signals in some direction by using
aluminum paper/tinfoil placed around the antenna.

I remark that this will maximize the emissions in the non-blocked direction,
extending their reach,
as this is one method used to concentrate WiFi signals.

This requires knowing exactly where the antenna is placed in the laptop,
if it does not have an external part, or even opening it up.

You could also use a weak external WiFi adapter to replace the internal one.

On Windows, your driver may have some useful parameter(s).
This is accessed in Device Manager, right-click on the device and select Properties,
then go to the Advanced tab.

Comment: So, if we use a external wifi adapter,is there a way we can decrease the range to some 2 or 3 meters around the adapter?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote it.

Comment: You will need to buy a real lousy one, or one which can be tuned low. I don't know of any such. To be fully safe it's better using a cable connection to the router, rather than WiFi.

Comment: Since I cannot comment due to low reputation, I would like to respond to **harrymc** this way: That tinfoil solution may result in so called directional antenna, which concentrates the emitted signal power in one direction. This concentration of signal power may *violate local laws for maximum transmission signal power* for private users in some areas. I don't know for other countries, but in Germany this could really cause some legal issues.

Comment: IIRC laptops use flat, polarised and already  very directional antennae on the lid

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Directional would mean that the angle in which a laptop is placed will affect reception. Did you notice such an effect?

Comment: @MPFelder: I also remarked about that, but I don't think that exceeding such limits is possible with a laptop (or desktop).